# MailMessage setting the Sender Name EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I want to send email with EWS using custom display name.

Here is my Code:

```
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage();
message.From = new EmailAddress("someone","one@two.com");
```

My expectation is that the received email to come from: `someone <one@two.com>`

Instead of this I get the email from: one `<one@two.com>`

Anybody know what would be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Have you tried this?

```
  new EmailAddress("someone <one@two.com>;");
```

---

PREVIOUS

`System.Net.Mail` Namespace has `MailAddress` class, not `EmailAddress`.

Are you using `System.Net.Mail`? And if not why not?

`MailAddress Constructor (String, String)` is this:

```
public MailAddress(
string address,
string displayName
)
```

so you should use this way:

```
message.From = new MailAddress("one@two.com","someone");
```

Comment: I`m using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data because I`m connect to exchangeService I use this way EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(exchangeService)

Comment: OK! Have you tried this?  new EmailAddress("someone <one@two.com>;" - look at my edit

Comment: I have tried, but I think I found the problem, probably the main problem is that my account has a setting with display name. This is a setting from the provider and probably I can`t overwrite. What is your opinion about this.

Comment: Using System.Net.Mail both tecniques work; interesting is looking at account restrinctions

Comment: I tried using `new EmailAddress("someone <one@two.com>;")` and it did not work.  - In fact it will not work because Exchange will grab the "correct" sender name from the account setting.  I gave up and ended up using the traditional System.Net.Mail.MailMessage etc.